# MySQL: How to list all tables that are used in a procedure?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a method or a query to retrieve all tables that are used in a procedure.
I tried `information_schema.routines`but it contains all the definition for a procedure.
Is there any system table that contains the dependency relationship for this ?
Or how can I get table names from the definitions using other language such as Python?
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

The current version of MySQL does not implement such a view in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

MySQL 8.0.13 added I_S.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE, which allows you to look up the tables used by a view. This was done for [WorkLog #11864](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=11864). That WorkLog notes compatibility with PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQL Server.

However, there is no WorkLog I can find for an hypothetical I_S.ROUTINE_TABLE_USAGE table. I checked PostgreSQL, and it has this view: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-routine-table-usage.html but MySQL does not.

So to get this information automatically, you would have to query the procedure body, and parse it for table references. Not an easy task.

Comment: Well it seems to be hard task.   
I tried sql_metadata package but it only supports SQL query not procedure.  
I'll try to find a way to parse routine body using Python.  
Thanks a lot!